# Where to run query activity for Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I have a query activity which populates a Data Extension, this data extension is then used within a Journey to populate entries. When activating the journey, MC creates an automation when a schedule for the journey has been setup.

Would it be advisable to edit this automation to add my query activity (that refreshes the source DE) to ensure the latest entries are added when the journey automation runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure the schedule for the entry event you can choose an existing automation. '[Schedule a Data Extension Entry Source](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_schedule_a_data_extension_entry_source.htm&type=5)'

> When you select Automation, the journey evaluates contact records when your chosen automation completes.

So you can create the automation, add any necessary activities, then select it with the configuration screen. JB will then add the injection step as the last step